# Applying no_sslv2.patch on Mac

Tags: python, macos, openssl

I'm running OS X 10.10 with default python installed (2.7.6). I'd like to apply the no_sslv2.patch (http://bugs.python.org/issue20207), but I'm sorta new to this and need some help figuring out how to do it. I understand that I need to use the "patch" command, but can't seem to know what the right response is when it asks about "File to patch:". Thanks!

Comment: You might have another problem... OS X supplies OpenSSL 0.9.8 by default. You might do better to build and install OpenSSL 1.0.1, and then compile and link Python against your 1.0.1 version. If you do, configure OpenSSL with: `export KERNEL_BITS=64; ./config no-ssl2 no-ssl3 enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128; make; sudo make install`. OpenSSL wil be conservatively configured, and you can find it in `/usr/local/ssl` after `make install`.

Comment: I can install the new openssl version, and then created a symbolic link pointing to this new version, however when I run this in python `print ssl._PROTOCOL_NAMES.items()`, I still get [(0, 'SSLv2'), (1, 'SSLv3'), (2, 'SSLv23'), (3, 'TLSv1')], which I'm assuming should not be the case, given that I compiled it without ssl2 or 3. Am I missing something?

Comment: OpenSSL 0.9.8 and 1.0.1 are *not* binary compatible, so you can't symlink it. And to further muddy the waters, Apple's `dyld` always uses a share object if available. So you'll have to modify paths to ensure Python uses the correct OpenSSL at runtime; or modify Python's configuration so it links against the static version of OpenSSL at compile time. See [Apple's dyld(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html) for more reading.

Comment: *"I still get [(0, 'SSLv2'), (1, 'SSLv3'), (2, 'SSLv23'), (3, 'TLSv1')]... Am I missing something?"* - before you invoke Python, set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` (its equivalent to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on Linux). Point it to `/usr/local/ssl/lib`.

Comment: I ran this: `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/ssl/lib:${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}` I then ran this to see if python started using the new openssl version, but doesn't appear so: `python -c "import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION"` since the result I got back was `OpenSSL 0.9.8za 5 Jun 2014`

Answer (score 0):

So, looks like i got it resolved. I ended up installing openssl through brew and that fixed my problem. I did the following after installing brew:
`brew update`
`brew install python --with-brewed-openssl`
After brew is done, it'll let you know to run `brew link --overwrite python` to force the link and overwrite all conflicting files. Once all that is done, on one machine, the mac ended up using the new version of openssl with python and on another, i had to change the PATH for that to work by making sure that /usr/local/bin was at the beginning of the PATH.